# ActionMailer - Attaching a file via Open

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

In my user_mailer, I'm trying to add an attachment like follows:

```
tempfile = File.new("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.attachment_file_name}", "w")
tempfile << open(a.authenticated_url())
tempfile.puts
attachments[a.attachment_file_name] = File.read("#{Rails.root.to_s}/tmp/#{a.attachment_file_name}")
```

This method: `a.authenticated_url()` is getting a valid URL, confirmed that

there's not error message but the file's being attached are corrupt and of the wrong size.

How can I attach a file to AcionMailer thats from a URL?

thanks

Comment: The file only contains "#<StringIO:0x104e96790>"